# Set UTF8 on mySQL

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8

ALL,

I'm trying to implements a mySQL communication from Python script. Here is what I have:

```
try:
   if append:
      self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(.....)
      self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
   else:
      self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(.....)
      self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
   self.conn.set_character_set('utf8;')
   self.cur.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
   self.cur.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
   self.cur.execute('SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix=ON')
   self.cur.execute('SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=barracuda')
   self.cur.execute('SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=ON')
# Database and table creation
```

Now my question is: should I run this utf8 and "SET.." queries for every connection or only when the database is created?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there's a character set named `'utf8;'`.

Comment: @abarnert, Well it worked, so I didn't look at the syntax. But my take on the question is that I should execute those lines whether I'm creating or adding. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These different commands do different things. And you're not even doing all of the right ones.

First, if you're using either pyMySQL or a later version of MySQLdb, pass `charset='utf8'` (notice that's `'utf8'` without a semicolon attached!) as an argument to the `connect` command. That means that your connection defaults to UTF-8, and also enabled `use_unicode` mode, and you don't need `set_character_set`. This is a better solution. You will, obviously, need to pass this every time you open a connection, as it's an argument to the connection.

If your library does not accept the `charset` argument, then you will have to use `set_character_set`, and you should do so immediately after the `connect`, every time you connect. But again, don't include that trailing `;` there.

Second, if this is Python 2.x, once you enable `use_unicode`, *all* SQL strings and *all* string-valued SQL parameters should be `unicode` objects, not `str` objects. You will often get away with not doing that properly (basically, if they're pure ASCII), but you should not depend on that. This is true even for the global, pragma, etc. statements at startup: use `u'…'` Unicode literals for those too.

Meanwhile, those first two `SET` should be part of what your database library does when you pass it a `charset` argument to the `connect` or call `set_character_set`. This is why older documentation sometimes says to pass `init_command='SET NAMES utf8'` if you can't pass `charset='utf8'`. So, you should never need to do them.

The other three `SET` queries, of course, have nothing to do with Unicode in the first place. They're all commands that only affect creation of new tables, but I have no idea if you ever create and drop tables in subsequent connections, or only when the database is initially created.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation. Couple of follow ups: 1. How do I know the MySQLDB version? 2. What is the minimal version required to use with your first sentence? 3. Maybe for compatibility sake just always use "set_character_set"? 4. The last 3 queries - they will just execute even if no new tables will be created, right?

Comment: One more thing if u know: What is the default encoding for mySQL connection on Windows (both client and server locally - development version)?

Comment: And another one - where should I enable "use_unicode"? I'm using Windows XP right now for development. And hopefully the last one - the first 2 SET commands are extra because they will do what set_character_set will do and so they are not needed, correct?